# ¿Cómo puedo pasar traspasar la sesion de mi usuario entre URL's en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

tengo un pequeño programa en Laravel en el que siempre que algún usuario quiera realizar alguna acción importante (editar o eliminar registros) debe solicitar un código de validación a el administrador, cuando el usuario genera una nueva solicitud, el "administrador" recibe un correo con una URL que redirige a una pantalla con el detallado de la solicitud, el detalle es que cuando el "administrador" abre esa URL los datos de su sesión no pueden ser leídos en esa "nueva" pagina que se abrió mediante la URL.

Tienen alguna idea de como puedo mandar los datos de la sesión del administrador a la "nueva" pestaña?.

Este es el método con el que genero la URL:

```
 public function enviasolicitud(Request $request){
    $username = $request->username;
    $utilidad = $request->utilidad;
    $usuario = DB::table('users')->where('name', $username)->select('id', 'email', 'area')->first();
    $URL = URL::temporarySignedRoute('vsolicitud', now()->addMinutes(5), ['username' => $username, 'utilidad' => $utilidad]);
    if(Mail::to($usuario->email)->send(new SolicitaCodigo($URL))){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Y este es el método con el que estoy intentado extraer los datos de la sesión del usuario:

```
public function RespondeSolicitud(Request $request){
    $respuesta = $request->valor;
    $funcion = $request->funcion;
    $usuario = auth()->user();
    if($respuesta  == 'acepta'){
      return self::SendCodigoUtilidad($usuario, $funcion);
    }
    else{
        return self::SendCodigoDenegado($usuario);
    }
```

De ante mano muchas gracias.